# Using the jQuery autocomplete widget in SharePoint search box

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, jquery-autocomplete

I implemented the autocomplete widget for jQuery for my SharePoint 2010 text box. But I see that the suggestion terms appearing with a Bullet point as shown below. Can anyone tell how can it be averted.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's something you can fix with CSS. However, if you have a proper reference to the jQueryUI CSS file, I don't think you should be seeing this. Make sure that reference is present and correct.